# Book about people who are taken through portals all over the world and wake up in a strange world

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

I read this book in 2019, it was a paperback and I believe the cover was green. It wasn't very thick.

It starts with a man waking up in a forest and he finds others after that. They are attacked in a cave they tried to fortify.  The man then finds an abandoned city of light with an infinity cross; I think they said "emerald city" or it was emerald green. The only other thing I can remember is that he keeps mentioning a heroine or a herald that is flying over him and he says he thinks he is the protector of these lands. The cross was referred to as an ankh.

I can't fully remember but I also think that there was others that the character ran into that ended up in the new world in a similar way. They referred to it as a Bermuda Triangle effect that happened in certain areas around the world.

I thought it was [*He Who Fights with Monsters*](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/26294/he-who-fights-with-monsters) but that's not it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you confirm whether some of these phrases; "City of light", "portals", "Bermuda triangle effect", "infinity symbol" are ***direct*** quotes from the book? Are there any other phrases you can particularly recall?